# Mapreduce Mapper explaination

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

There is an NCDC weather data set example in Hadoop definite guide.
The Mapper class code is as follows

```
Example 2-3. Mapper for maximum temperature example
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
public class MaxTemperatureMapper
 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
 private static final int MISSING = 9999;

 @Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
 throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 String line = value.toString();
 String year = line.substring(15, 19);
 int airTemperature;
 if (line.charAt(87) == '+') { // parseInt doesn't like leading plus signs
 airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));
 } else {
 airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87, 92));
 }
 String quality = line.substring(92, 93);
 if (airTemperature != MISSING && quality.matches("[01459]")) {
 context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
 }
 }
}
```

And the driver code is:

```
Example 2-5. Application to find the maximum temperature in the weather dataset
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
public class MaxTemperature {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 if (args.length != 2) {
 System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
 System.exit(-1);
 }

 Job job = new Job();
 job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
 job.setJobName("Max temperature");
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

 job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
 job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);
 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

 System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

I'm not able to understand since we pass a file containing multiple lines why there is no iteration on lines. The code seems as if it is processing on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

The book explains what  `Mapper<LongWritable, Text,`means... The key is the offset of the file. The value is a line.

It also mentions that `TextInputFormat` is the default mapreduce input type, which is a type of FileInputFormat

```
public class TextInputFormat
extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable,Text>
```

And therefore, the default input types must be Long, Text pairs

As the JavaDoc says

> Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. Keys are the position in the file, and values are the line of text..

The book also has sections on defining custom RecordReaders

You need to call `job.setInputFormatClass` to change it to read anything other than single lines